# Regex get string from string

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, regex

I have `NSString` that contain this string :

```
c&&(b.signature=Rk(c));return ql(a,b)}
```

The `RK` can be any two chars.

I try to get the `RK` from the string with (RegexKitLit):

```
NSString *functionCode = [dataStr2 stringByMatching:@".signature=(.*?)\(" capture:1L];
```

and `functionCode` is always `nil`.Any idea what wrong?

Comment: If you know where the 2 characters you want are, why do you need a regex?

Comment: i wrote that it can be Rk and it can be tU or any other two letters

Comment: But since you know WHERE they are, can't you just extract the characters at those positions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother with regular expressions for this. If the format of the string is always the same then you can simply do:

```
NSString *dataStr2 = @"c&&(b.signature=Rk(c));return ql(a,b)}";
NSString *functionCode = [dataStr2 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(16, 2)];
```

If the string is not quite so fixed then base it on the position of the `=`.

```
NSString *dataStr2 = @"c&&(b.signature=Rk(c));return ql(a,b)}";
NSRange equalRange = [dataStr2 rangeOfString:@"="];
NSString *functionCode = [dataStr2 substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(equalRange.location + equalRange.length, 2)];
```